# Not understanding a rule of inference.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am reading about a axiom system like this:

Connectives:$\lnot,\rightarrow$ 
Axioms:
(A1) $A_1 \rightarrow (A_2 \rightarrow A_1)$ 
(A2) $(A_1 \rightarrow (A_2 \rightarrow A_3)) \rightarrow ((A_1 \rightarrow A_2) \rightarrow (A_1 \rightarrow A_3))$ 
(A3) $(\lnot A_2 \rightarrow \lnot A_1) \rightarrow ((\lnot A_2 \rightarrow A_1 ) \rightarrow A_2)$

Rule of inference:
(i)MP (which I know)
(ii)Substitution rule (which I don't know)

The description of substitution rule was like this:-

> In addition to modus ponens, we have a substitution rule: we may substitute any wf for all occurrences of statement letter in a given wf.

But I still didn't understand this inference.Can someone explain this to me with a concrete example?

Comment: Pick a well-formed formula and put it in the same position as the variable symbol in the formula for every occurnce of that variable symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider the difference between [page 3] the symbols $A_1,A_2,\ldots$, called *statement letters* and the symbols $\mathscr A, \mathscr B, \ldots$ that are *statement forms*.

The fist one are the symbols of the alphabet of the formal language; we use them with *connectives* to produce *formulas* (wf): $A_1 \to \lnot A_2$.

The *statement forms* [commonly called [*schemata* (singular: *schema*)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/)] are not part of the formal language but are used in the meta-language as names for formulas.

As you see [page 28 and 29] the three logical axioms as well as Modus Ponens rule are formulated with statement forms.

Consider e.g. logical axiom (A1): $\mathscr B \to (\mathscr C \to \mathscr B)$.

Formula $A_1 \to (A_2 \to A_1)$ as well as $(A_1 \to A_1) \to (A_2 \to (A_1 \to A_1))$ and many more are instances of the shema.

The alternative approach is to state axioms not as schemata but directly as formula of the language [page 39]: $A_1 \to (A_2 \to A_1)$.

In this case, without schematic axioms, we have lost the "rule" to produce instances of axiom.

To restore this possibility, we need a supplementary rule:

> In addition to modus ponens, we have a substitution rule: we may substitute any wf for all occurrences of a statement letter in a given wf.

See also John Corcoran, [Schemata: The Concept of Schema in the History of Logic (2006)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38327394_Schemata_The_Concept_of_Schema_in_the_History_of_Logic).