# There is no substitution rule?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Lets say there is a formal language $L$ with a bunch of axioms (example from mendelson). 
(A1) $A \to (B \to A)$ 
(A2) $(A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \to B ) \to (A \to C))$ 
(A3) $(\neg A \to \neg B) \to ((\neg A \to B ) \to A)$

The only rule of inference is modus ponens.

But then I fall into a confusion.I can't do any proof with this unless i introduce the substitution rule (a inference).And substitution rule is indeed used in all of the proof of theorems of that language.But the substitution rule is not mentioned as a inference rule in the list of inferences(there is only modus ponens).Why?

Comment: I haven't read mendelson, so I'm not 100% sure (which is why this is a comment), but many authors introduce these rules as axiom _schemas_. That is, for _any_ formulas $A$, $B$, and $C$ these count as axioms. This means "axiom 1" (and 2 and 3) is actually a countable family of axioms, on for each pair of formulas $(A,B)$.

Comment: You can definitely "substitute" since one can write $A = f(A_1,...,A_n)$ and $B = g(B_1,...,B_m)$, for example, where $f$ and $g$ are boolean functions.

Comment: Already [asked and answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4011016/not-understanding-a-rule-of-inference): Mendelson's axioms are *schemata*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Mendelson's textbook](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA3), page 3:

> let us apply the name *statement form* to an expression built up from the statement letters $A, B, C$, and so on by appropriate applications of the propositional connectives.

> 1. All statement letters (capital italic letters) and such letters with numerical subscripts [*footnote*: For example, $A_1, A_2, B_1, C_2, \ldots$] are statement forms.

> 2. If $\mathscr B$ and $\mathscr C$ are statement forms, then so are $(\lnot \mathscr B), (\mathscr B \land \mathscr C)$ [*and so on*].

Axioms (A1), (A2) and (A3) [page 28] are expressed with *statement forms*: $\mathscr B → (\mathscr C → \mathscr B)$ abnd **not** with statement letters: $B → (C → B)$.

This means that they are *schemata*: i.e. rules for producing instances writing formulas (made with statement letters) in place of statement forms.

Thus, substitution rule is embedded into the use of schemata.